# Pointers / advice on Ubuntu Server install on HP Gen 8 G1610T microserver

Tags: system-installation, hp, raid

I've recently purchased an HPE Microserver G8 GP1610T, 120GB SSD drive and a couple of 2TB drives to build an Ubuntu based server with the OS on the SSD drive and two 2TB drives as mirrored (RAID1) storage. I don't require dual-boot capability.

In reading through existing posts on this forum and elsewhere it appears that this isn't exactly straightforward with issues around recognizing and booting from drives connected to the Optical Disk sata port, utilizing the HP 'RAID' controller and fan noise. The posts however all date back to mid-2015, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and before.

My questions are therefore:

1. Do the more recent versions of Ubuntu make any of this easier and solve the fan noise issue?
2. Is the HP 'RAID' controller worth using or is the Ubuntu software RAID the better option?
3. Do I bother with the SSD drive or just run the OS off a uSD card?
4. Any pointers to 'HowTo' guides for this type of installation, especially around the RAID controller / disk configuration?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tel you what is best for you but i will tel you what i did on our internal servers.

I always installed Ubuntu or Debian servers on Linux software raid.
I already had to recover a broken drive and that was realy easy to do. also the system would just boot with only one drive active. Just hotswap and add it to the lvm volume againe.

What i would not do is running your os of the SSD but of the 2 disks. If your SSD fails you lost your entire os if one of the disk fails you just order a new one and your still ok.

to set this up i have used this guide in the past with succes.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID

You can even do some exotic stuff and use raid 1 for data and os and use raid 0 for swap